# Postgres - Cannot Join Json Array Values on UUID

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, join, uuid

So I have one table `Profession`:

```
UUID UUID,
Name TEXT
```

Where `UUID` is `uuid1, uuid2, uuid3, etc.`

Then another table `Degrees`:

```
 DegreeName TEXT,
 Record JSON
```

Where the `Record->'Professions'` json record may contain a list of `Profession.uuid`, such as `{"Professions":"[uuid1,uuid2]"}`, though the field could be `NULL` such as `{"Professions":"[]"}`.

Here is how I am trying to join the two tables:

```
SELECT prof.uuid, prof.Name, d.DegreeName

FROM Profession prof
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DegreeName, json_array_elements(Record->'Professions') prof_uuid
        FROM  Degrees
    ) d
ON d.prof_uuid::TEXT=prof.uuid::TEXT
```

When I do this, I only get Nulls. Note that I cast to `TEXT` because I cannot cast the `Professions` array to a `UUID` because of blanks.

I have tried manually searching for the `Profession` table using a value from the `Professions` list and it works:

```
SELECT *
FROM Profession
WHERE uuid = 'someprofuuid'
```

Is there some cast I missing?

Comment: You can't be using Postgres as the query won't even run. `[DegreeName]` is an invalid identifier in SQL. And `json_array_elements('Professions')` passes an invalid JSON string with the value `'Professions'` to the function. And `ARRAY` isn't a valid data type definition.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the code on my Question, but the problem still remains.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the complete `create table` statement. I have no idea what data type `array` is supposed to be. `text[]`? `jsonb` with a JSON array value? `jsonb[]` storing an array of JSON values?  What is the content of that column? Please **[edit]** add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)

Comment: I apologize I am relatively new to querying JSON. The `Professions` field is on a `json` type field called `Record`. I added in example data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was I was using `json_array_elements` instead of `json_array_elements_text`. When I switched that, the join worked:

```
SELECT prof.uuid, prof.Name, d.DegreeName

FROM Profession prof
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DegreeName, json_array_elements_text(Record->'Professions') prof_uuid
        FROM Degrees
    ) d
ON d.prof_uuid::TEXT=prof.uuid::TEXT
```